# can I put external jar higher priority than android.jar

Tags: android

I am using apache httpClient.jar on my android app. Since android.jar has same packages and classes as httpClient.jar, former is used which does not have consume method.

I want to put httpClient.jar higher priority than android.jar which has the method. Then below exception can be resolved.

I put it higher priority in eclipse but the exception is still thrown.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:177)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1619)
```

Comment: Did you try to set httpClient.jar as exported?

Comment: Yes. I set all of the jars as exported.